# Closing a google cloud account billing so no one can reopen it?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, billing

I recently worked with a corporation and they gave me the user pass of main gmail account that apps are using and said use your credit card on it and we will change it in 1 month , i submitted my credit account and submitted my verification document , after one month they changed password of the main account with (2 step verification enabled !)
because some how they were the original creator of the account ! so the put me outside of it and they fired me ,they are still using my credit card after telling them that i report my card stolen the gave me Billing administrator role for the account no i see close in billing section how can i close that account billing that no one can re open it,
i just my credit card out and don't care that main account deletes or suspends !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to open a case  the Google Cloud Platform Billing Support:

[Google Cloud Platform Billing Support](https://support.google.com/cloud/contact/cloud_platform_billing)

They should be able to assist you with anything related to billing accounts.